# Initialize @property of custom type in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've got a view controller that contains a `@property` which is a custom subclass of UIView (we can call it CanvasView). This CanvasView is getting `@synthesized`, but there is some custom initialization I want to do on it. I know I need to implement `-(id)initWithFrame` on CanvasView and do my custom initialization there, but either `-(id)initWithFrame` is not getting called, or `[self = [super initWithFrame:frame]` is failing. Does `@synthesize` call `initWithFrame`? And how can I tell if my `[super initWithFrame:frame]` is failing?

Note: I have built the interface so far programmatically, so `-(id)initWithCoder` or `-(id)initWithNibNamed:bundle:` shouldn't be used here (I think). I'm guessing the answer to this is to start building my interface with nibs.

Comment: Don't be afraid of nib files. It's not magic. It just follows a logic just as the code you write yourself. The xib file contained in your project is just an XML file with the same info you would manually set in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@synthesize only generates code for the setter and getter of your property based on the options you specified in its declaration.

How are you initializing the instance of CanvasView?

Comment: Yep, I had accidentally commented out my initialization and assignment along with some other code and had gotten myself confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All `@synthesize` does is create a getter and setter for your property.  You'll still need to initalize the your object prior to using it.

Answer (score 0):

As was said, properties do not create the object behind the property. That is something you'll have to do somewhere. The best place is in one of the `initXXX:` initializers, but sometimes you need some info that is not present yet, like info about the window, etc. Then you can do it in the `awakeFromNib` method. That is "called" when the nib has completely loaded.

Another way to do this is *lazy initialization*. Even if you use `@synthesize`, nothing prevents you from writing your own `getProperty` (where "Property" should be replaced by the real name of the property) method. There you can lazy initialize the object, i.e. you don't create it before it is needed the first time. If the ivar is `nil`, you `alloc` and initialize the desired object and store it in the ivar. Then you return it. If it is not `nil`, you simply return what is in the ivar already. The synthesized `setProperty:` will still take care of retaining the new value and releasing the old one, if the property is an object.

Lazy initialization example:

```
- (MyObjType *) getFoo
{
    if (!_foo)
    {
        _foo = [[MyObjType alloc] init...   ];
        _foo.something = 33;
        _foo.garble = 1.234;
    }
    return [_foo autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are not going to use a nib, try the following:

In your view controller:

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    //...

    CanvasView *canvasView = [[CanvasView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,self.view.frame.size.width-20,self.view.frame.size.height-20)];
    [self.view addSubview:canvasView];
    [canvasView release];

    //...
}
```

And then in your CanvasView (ensure it extends UIView):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
       // Perform custom init stuff...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps!